# Window shrinked to quarter of screen size when running app from Android Phone on Appaccelerator Titanium

Tags: android, titanium

I have build an iPhone app and using same code to compile Android app. When I run the app in the phone (HTC Desire) instead in emulator, the main window shrinked to the quarter of the screen size, everything else is working fine except this. Can someone please let me know if there is any configuration to look for in Titanium ?

- Ubuntu
- Appaccelerator Tatanium Studio
- HTC Desire

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2011/06/new-defaults-for-android-layouts-in-1-7.html) could possibly help you?

Comment: This is exactly what you are looking for. Explaining it a bit the size changes because the phone you are using has a higher screen density then the emulator version you are using. Add the code they mention in this link to your TiApp.xml and reinstall on device and it will fix the format.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at screenshots on Appaccelerator website I see that Android phone is presented by HTC Hero, which is kind of old for 2011. This makes me think that Appaccelerator is not aware of newest high-density devices like Desire. If Appaccelerator uses physical coordinates for pixels then on high-density phones you'll get exactly the behavior you describe.

Anyways, phrase *patent-pending development technology* stated on the Appaccelerator website is already an alarming sign against using it.